# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "controller_manager"

Tags: gazebo, catkin-make, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS jade on an Ubuntu 14.04 OS and I am trying to connect the Gazebo simulator to ROS. I have followed the tutorials to connect Gazebo to ROS on the Gazebo website, and now I am trying to download the URDF of the Pioneer 3dx robot (since that is the robot I am using), but I am running into a problem. I have placed the URDF file from a github site into the src directory of my catkin_ws, but whenever I run "catkin_make" I always get this error:

CMake Error at /opt/ros/jade/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"controller_manager" with any of the following names:

```
controller_managerConfig.cmake
controller_manager-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "controller_manager" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
set "controller_manager_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
files.  If "controller_manager" provides a separate development package or
SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
ua_ros_p3dx/p3dx_control/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/tatum/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/tatum/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed

I have looked online to find an answer to this problem but the answers posted do not help me. I think this has to do with the fact that the the other questions were based on the indigo distribution. Please help!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215766/could-not-find-a-package-configuration-file-provided-by-%22controller_manager%22/) by [thumper](https://answers.ros.org/users/23555/thumper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-08-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't have the `controller_manager` package installed.
As `ros_control` is not yet release for Jade, try to clone the `ros_control` repository with `git clone https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control.git -b jade_devel` and try again.

If (when) it is release, you can install it using `sudo apt-get install ros-jade-controller-manager'.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thumper](https://answers.ros.org/users/23555/thumper/) on 2015-08-13**:
Thank you so much!!!! It worked!